# How to escape double quotes in string?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'd like double quotes to appear within the following string so it looks like:

```
"hi there == "
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[s appendString:@""""];
[s appendString:@"hi there == ""\n\r"];
```

Instead I only get:

```
hi there ==
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be noted that
    [s appendString:@"hi there == ""\n\r"];
unintentionally takes advantage of a C/C++/ObjC feature: two string literals placed next to each other (with or without whitespace in between) are concatenated.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
[s appendString:@"hi there == \"\n\r"];
```

`\"` is what is needed for `"` - This is standard C formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Although Its late but we can Try this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"Hi There=\" Other text"];
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to append a slash (\) before the quote (") to ge the expected output.

```
[s appendString:@"\"hi there == \"\n\r"];
```

Output will be "hi there == "

Comment: -​1 for basically just reposting the content of an existing answer 4 years later. As an aside, you mean "prepend" rather than "append", here.