# Is it possible to include a quotation mark as part of an nsstring?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have a label that displays inches. I would like to display the number with the inch symbol (") or quotation mark. Can I do this with an nsstring?
Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, the "inch" symbol is properly a double-prime (″) rather than a double-quote ("). Worst is when people use smart quotes for inches, I suppose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape double quotes in string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352323/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-string)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Sure, you just need to escape the quotation mark.

```
NSString *someString = @"This is a quotation mark: \"";
NSLog(@"%@", someString );
```

Output:

```
This is a quotation mark: "
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use **Double Quote Escape Sequence** here. You need to escape it using a **backslash** :

```
NSString *str = @"Hello \"World\"";
NSLog(@"Output : %@",str);

Output : Hello "World"
```

There are some other **Escape Sequences** also. Take a look at it :

```
\b    Backspace
\f    Form Feed
\n    Newline
\t    Horizontal Tab
\v    Vertical Tab
\\    Backslash
\’    Single Quote
\”    Double Quote
\?    Question Mark
```

Answer (score 6):

As use of back slash **\"** has already mentioned so I am answering different. You can use [ASCII Code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) too.

[ASCII Code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) of **" (double quote)** is **34**.

```
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%cThis is a quotation mark: %c", 34, 34];
 NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

**And Output is:**
"This is a quotation mark: "

**Swift 4.0 Version**

```
let str = String(format: "%cThis is a quotation mark: %c", 34, 34)
print(str)
```

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT**

```
let string = " TEST  \"  TEST "
println(string)
```

output in console is - TEST  "  TEST

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can include a quotation mark in an `NSString` literal using the backslash to escape it.

For example, to put the string `Quote " Quote` in a string literal, you would use this:

```
@"Quote \" Quote"
```

A backslash followed by a quotation mark simply inserts the quotation mark into the string.

Answer (score 2):

If the string is a literal string, then you can use the escape character to add a quotation mark inside a string.

```
NSString *string = @"16\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for **Swift 5, Xcode 10.2**

```
let myText = #"This is a quotation mark: ""#
print(myText)
```

Output:

> This is a quotation mark: "