# how to add double quotes after '=' symbol in nsstring?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a weird issue, were I need to add "" after '=' symbol in nsstring. Below is the example

```
NSString *codes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sessionToken];
NSString *slash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth session_token=%@",codes]; << here I have to add the "".
```

i have tried with

```
NSString *slash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth session_token=\"%@\"",codes];
```

but it didn't work the result is showing like this `\"value\"`.

Comment: have you tried [NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth session_token=\"%@\"\"",codes]; ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934886/is-it-possible-to-include-a-quotation-mark-as-part-of-an-nsstring

Comment: When you say 'it's showing like `\"value\"`' how are you showing it?  If it's in the debugger or as part of an NSLog of some larger object (e.g. a dictionary) you, the logging system sometimes puts the backslashes in.

Comment: @JeremyP, Yes it is showing in the debugger. Since my service has the header tag as `auth session_token="Token"`, so it is not matching since I am getting my token dynamically, I have to use the previous mentioned way i.e. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth session_token=\"%@\"\"",codes]`

Answer (score 10):

A backslash`(\)` followed by a quotation mark`(")` will inserts the quotation mark into NSString.

```
NSString *slash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth session_token=\"%@\"",@"1233"];
NSLog(@"slash %@", slash);
```

Output is

```
[23273:a0f] slash auth session_token="1233"
```

[Is it possible to include a quotation mark as part of an nsstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934886/is-it-possible-to-include-a-quotation-mark-as-part-of-an-nsstring)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
NSString *slash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth session_token=""""""",codes];
```

I've recently done some thing similar and this seemed to work for me