# Double quotes in NSString iOS SDK

Tags: ios, ipad, nsstring, double, quotes

I need to have a string like this,

`Content-Disposition = name="uploaded file"` in my HTTP request header.

I tried using escape sequences \" like this (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934886/is-it-possible-to-include-a-quotation-mark-as-part-of-an-nsstring/23808689#23808689))

```
NSString *valueString = @"name=\"uploadedfile\" ";
```

it returns me an output like this : "Content-Disposition" = "name=\"uploadedfile\"";

how can i do this? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just NSLog the valueString and check what is the output, if it is correct, then the issue will be with some other part

Comment: Isn't your header formed wrong btw? Shouldn't it be: Content-Disposition: name="YOUR NAME"?

Comment: `    NSString *name = @"name=\"uploadedfile\"";
    NSLog(@"%@",name);` //Result = name="uploadedfile"

Comment: @MidhunMP I get this after NSLogging.

    "Content-Disposition" = "name=\"uploadedfile\"";

Comment: @AlexanderW 

This is how the request header is being formed

Request Header: 

{
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
    "Content-Disposition" = "name=\"uploadedfile\"";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    "User-Agent" = "Collectors/1.0 (iPad; iOS 7.1.1; Scale/2.00)";
}

Comment: @nmh If you notice closely, I'm doing the same thing as you have mentioned in your answer and the problem is the \" are also getting printed. Please see the above comment to check how it is being printed.

Comment: Show your full code which return wrong value?

Comment: @nmh This is how I'm setting it.

NSString *valueString = @"name=\"uploadedfile\"";                       
[request setValue:valueString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Disposition"];