# Localizable.strings - The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, localizable.strings

If I copy something from textedit or web and paste it to localizable file it shows this compilation error. If I type those in localizable file it does not show any error. I am assuring you that I using the correct format and ';' in the file.

```
"New" = "New";
"In Progress" = "In Progress";
"Waiting" = "Waiting";
"Closed" = "Closed";
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems like SVN is having some issue with this file. As it consider it to be a binary file. It is inserting a lot of non printable characters between each characters. I still couldn't find a proper solution. Just changing the Localizable.string files from production PC for avoiding any issue with it.

**Update:** Updating the SVN client (smartSVN) to the latest version solved the issue. It seems one of my colleague was using a older version. When he commited the change to localizable file it caused the error.

Answer (score 211):

- Use **plutil** from the Terminal:

you have to run it for each version of the localizable file. E.g

1. `cd` into your project root
2. `cd eb.lproj` - you can replace this with
       any localisation you are working with.
3. `plutil -lint Localizable.strings`

When you run step 3, you will either be shown an error, telling you what is wrong with your file. Or you will be told the file is OK

> Note that plutil output is bad, it seems it always says "Unexpected character at line 1" but above that output, it prints other stuff like missing semicolon on line 121, and that is the real error

Comment: It shows me `Unexpected character " at line 1`, and it is the first string like `"app_name"="Any Name"`

Comment: Note that plutil output is bad, it seems it always says "Unexpected character at line 1" but above that output, it prints other stuff like missing semicolon on line 121, and that is the real error...

Comment: For me plutil was showing the same error at line 1, although there wasn't any. But `pl < Localizable.strings` worked for me.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj you just saved me sooooo much time ty! That commend worked

Comment: `plutil` doesn't work. Only `pl`.

Answer (score 78):

For me, it was missing semi-colons. If you use a tool to generate `.strings` file, make sure there are no un-escaped quotes that may 'eat' the delimiting semi-colons.

Answer (score 62):

Fastest way to detect the line with the issued string is to :

- right click the strings file and
- then Open as/ASCII property list.

Xcode will immediately tell you in what line there's an error.

Comment: Superb solution

Comment: Very easy to identify the issue

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwwww!!

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 45):

**pl < Localizable.strings**
is better than **plutil -lint Localizable.strings**

Log will show something like this

2019-08-14 16:39:34.066 pl[21007:428513] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 427. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2019-08-14 16:39:34.068 pl[21007:428513] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 427. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2019-08-14 16:39:34.071 pl[21007:428513] *** Exception parsing ASCII property list: NSParseErrorException Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character / at line 1" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character / at line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Missing ';' on line 427" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Missing ';' on line 427}}

Comment: This is the best solution and it resolved my problem. "plutil" shows an error on the 1st symbol, but "pl < Localizable.strings" is really better and it show the proper number of line where you have a problem with *.plist

Comment: Definitely the better solution. It gives you more information and the line number for the issue, rather than a generic output.

Comment: this helped me easily find the root cause

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 12):

I know this question was asked long ago but my scenario and solution is little bit different.
Today I faced same issue but when I tried to check the issue using

**plutil -lint Localizable.strings**

I got **OK** status which means everything is fine, then I tried to find issue using

**pl < Localizable.strings**

But again I got file text printed with no error mentioned, then I tried a trick and it worked for me.

- Right click on the Localizable.strings file
- Then select option **Open As** option
- Then select option **ASCII Property List**

That's it, XCode shows me the issue with line number and the issue was I had this *DéjàVerified* text as key on specified line, this helps me to identify and solve the issue, I hope it will save someone's time.

Cheers!

Comment: Where can we read the docs for this pl command? Can't find the < anywhere; anyway this should be part of Xcode and tell us where exactly is the problem instead of telling us to go find a wrong char in a file with hundreds of thousands of chars! stupid... open as ASCII Property List is not working here.

Answer (score 11):

There can be multiple reasons for this:

1. Semicolon is missing at the end.
2. Multiple semicolons at the end.
3. " within the message which should be escaped by \".
4. Extra character after semicolon.
5. Invalid white space in the file.
6. Other invalid characters in the file.
7. Merge conflict characters in the file!

`<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======` and `>>>>>>>`.

Please note that `plutil -lint Localizable.strings` returned `OK` for point-2 & 7!

Comment: this is the second time I have this problem because of missing Semi-colon. I had a very long error log but they could not bother to mention a missing Semi-colon

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was missing "=" between a string pair. Even plutil did not help me to spot the error line. I manually checked each string pair. :/

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax seems to be fine, the only thing that I can see can "break" your file and cause this error is the quote character. Make sure to use the reqular one `"` and not in any other form like `″` for example.

Comment: No it's not the case. There are some non printable character in the strings! May be its related to xocde update or something!

Comment: You can post it in your answer and we can analyze it. Hard to say what’s not working with the little info you’ve provided so far.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure the strings file name is always `Localizable.strings`

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same issue and i resolved it by commenting or removed unused strings in my **Localizable.String** file :)

Comment: My SVN is considering the .string file as binary file. Are you sure you ran into something like this?

Answer (score 2):

I once had a similar error and it turned out that there was an URL in the middle of the file, like this:

```
// Some Comment 1
"Some key 1" = "Some value 1";
http://...whatever...
// Some Comment 2
"Some key 2" = "Some value 2";
```

When calling `plutil -lint` on that file the output was:

```
Unexpected character / at line 1
```

Well, the first character indeed was `/` as the file started with a comment but the problem resolved after removing the URL; or turning it into a comment which it actually should have been. Note that the URL was nowhere near the beginning of the strings file, it was about in the middle of a 6000 lines string file. I was only able to find it by browsing through commit history and always look at the changes.

Answer (score 2):

if missing ";" at end of the all lines in  Localizable.string file, this error can occur.

eg :- 
"header_text" = "Current Language";
"change_language" = "Change Language";

"header_text" = "වත්මන් භාෂාව";
"change_language" = "භාෂාව වෙනස් කරන්න";

Comment: Great, Thanks bro, Saved my day (Y)

Answer (score 2):

This tool can help solve this problem, just select your localizable.strings file, it will help you find out which line format is wrong, it can save a lot of time

https://localizable.appdevtool.io/

Answer (score 1):

This may be because the translation file format is wrong.

You can download a mac software called [Localizable](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/localizable-%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E5%B7%A5%E5%85%B7/id1268616588?mt=12).

This is the download link: https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/localizable-%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E5%B7%A5%E5%85%B7/id1268616588?mt=12,

you only need to drag Localizable.strings to the software and it will It is useful to tell you which line in the file may have a problem. It saved me a lot of time. Now I share it with you.

I hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your info.plist is not in correct form . check it properly. I also had the same issue . I resolved it by modifying my info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this experience:

- external translator doing the work inside Visual Code or other text editors
- Files not working and getting an error like this one: ( testing with plutil -lint )

  `Localizable.strings: Unexpected character " at line 1 
  CardRatingView.strings: Unexpected character / at line 2`

**I just created a new file within XCode and copy pasted all the file content and suddenly everything was working properly.**

I guess something can go wrong / corrupting the file itself while working with other text editors.

Answer (score 0):

If showing something like `Unexpected character " at line 1, and it is the first string like "app_name"="Any Name"`

**Check that the file is UTF16**

Comment: Why? String files are allowed to be UTF-8 as well. All my string files are always UTF-8 and that has never been a problem. Actually there is an Xcode setting that allows you to choose which files Xcode shall write on output when copying string files and even that setting allows you to choose UTF-8, UTF-16 or binary.

Comment: Hey yeah, I've realized later what you are describing. I think the error is due to Xcode thinking the file is in one encoding, while factually it's in another.

Comment: UTF-16 files require a BOM. If there is no BOM, macOS usually assumes UTF-8. But if you want to use UTF-8 in a place where UTF-16 is expected, this often works as well if you place an UTF-8 BOM (BOMs are optional for UTF-8 but macOS usually recognizes them). https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, all my formatting was correct. Checking for illegal characters using `plutil -lint Localizable.strings` and using ruby libraries like `"utf8_utils"` also didn't work at finding the illegal characters. BUT when I pasted the Localizable.strings contents into the Terminal app while running `irb`, it did show me the weird characters.

```
"PercentComplete" = "%d procent gennemført";
```

Pasted into irb:

```
"PercentComplete"\U+FFC2\U+FFA0= "%d procent gennemf\U+FFC3\U+FFB8rt";
```

Then all I had to do was a regex replace to fix those weird white space characters: `\U+FFC2\U+FFA0`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the plutil suggestion I understood that to make it work you have to delete also any \ or * as are not read as comments and, important, add a ; to the end of the file. Xcode 11.5.

Answer (score 0):

If **pl** and **plutil** show no problems, check the file's encoding. I had a similar problem twice and in my case it was due to incorrect encoding, though I have no idea how it has been changed (I literally added a single line in the middle of the file in X-Code). Converting from UTF-16LE to UTF-16BE in some editor (I used Android Studio) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had an NSLocalizedString in my code that contained a string interpolation e.g. `NSLocalizedString("\(product.price ?? "")per_month")`. When I exported localisations this got added to my strings file, which was then in the wrong format. It threw me off because my strings file in Xcode looked fine, but actually the file gets updated as part of the export localisations process, and errors were creeping in there.

If anyone things they might be having the same issue try calling genstrings separately and seeing if the newly generated file is in the correct format. Make sure you save your strings first as this will overwrite your strings file : `find ./ -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -SwiftUI -o en.lproj`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had one line with using `”` instead of `"` and that breaks the file. My code editor did not detect this difference.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the similar issue where i didn't escape the string value with backslash `\` for one of my string's value.

**Before:**

> "INVALID_NUMBER" = "It seems you're entering invalid number. Number should starts with "0" or "7"";

**Updated:**

> "INVALID_NUMBER" = "It seems you're entering invalid number. Number should starts with \"0\" or \"7\"";

Backslashes are required when you want to display the quotation marks `"`

Please, have a quick look at here for [How to include Quotation mark in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934904/940096)