# Populating Localizable.strings file with Terminal genstring command in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, localization

Trying to localize a SwiftUI app, I was under the impression that things had gotten a lot simpler.
I created the `Localizable.strings` files for both of my supported languages, but I can't populate them with the usual Terminal genstring command : `genstrings -o en.lproj *.swift`, even though I am launching this command from the correct directory.

Does anyone know if genstring is broken in swiftUI or if there is another way ?
Would HATE to have to go through the hundred strings in my app...

I did find many articles online about localization in SwiftUI, but nothing that clearly explains it.

My understanding is that in SwiftUI, we can simply write things like

`Text("A text to be displayed")`and this would be understood as a `LocalizedStringKey`by default.

Am I wrong ?

Added Screenshot of issue after trying @Asperi's solution :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-SwiftUI` option (as in variant below, or any other used)

```
$ find ./ -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -a -SwiftUI -o en.lproj
```

for details

```
$ man genstrings
```

Comment: Thanks again Asperi, The strings were generated, but they are greyed, not red as usual and the build fails with this warning : could not decode input file using specified encoding: Unicode (UTF-8). I did set the text Encoding to UTF 8 in Xcode though. Screenshot added to question...

Comment: @Esowes, this might be due to conflict of encodings in existed & newly generated .strings files. Try to store somewhere existed Localizable.strings (if any present) files and regenerate from scratch *without* option `-a`, then copy-paste old content using Xcode - it automatically detects encodings.

Comment: OK, after running `pl < Localizable.strings`, as suggested by Jerome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57491174/8736449),  I found out the issue was just a missing ";"... Thanks for the help.