# Print double quote inside @""

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape double quotes in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352323/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-string)

I need to print a "abc" inside @""

My current string is

```
[displayLbl setText:@"press stop"];
```

But i need:

```
[displayLbl setText:@"press "stop""];
```

How can i do this?

Comment: you have to escape the double quotes.

Comment: I don't know why people include xcode in their question. Xcode is IDE and It has nothing to do with your objective -c problems.. Edited your title

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[displayLbl setText:@"press \"stop\""];
```

Answer (score 3):

Roland Keesom's answer is of course correct. But you might also consider to use *typographic quotation marks*, which usually look better:

```
[displayLbl setText:@"press “stop”"];
```

(You only have to find them on the keyboard (-: )

Comment: @Downvoter: Any comment?

Comment: Yes he explicitly asked for "press "stop"" inside the string, that's a different character.You should have said "press \"stop\"", or a string with format where characters were '"' .

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: That had already been said by Roland Keesom. I have explicitely stated that this is an alternative suggestion that makes a better visual appearance. - But never mind ...