# Alternatives to @""?

Tags: ios, xcode, string

I have a string that has multiple `"` in it, which is written inside of `@""` and of course, xcode sees this as me ending the `@"`. Is there any alternatives I can use for `@""` that would do the same thing?

Comment: Escape them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352323/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's done with escape chars. `@"My name is \"Someone\". Blabla.";`