# Compare JSON response to a String

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

So my iOS app sends data (json) to the server and, if all goes well, the server sends back a json response `{"status":"ok"}`. I was thinking that I don't need to really parse this response because it is merely a confirmation so I could just compare the response I get with a static `NSString` which will be `"status":"ok"`.

The fact that my intended String has a quotation mark makes it very tricky for me to compare my response data to this String.

I'm sure there is a way to do what I want to do.

Comment: Playing with fire. The server could send back `{    "status":"ok"}`. Treat is as JSON, not a string.

Comment: What happens when things don't go well?

Comment: Exactly, was a stupid idea. Actually i knew it's not what I should do, I'm just lazy sometimes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the answer you want.  At some point you will want to do one of the following:

- Add a new field to the response to support a new app version (perhaps a pid or nonce)
- Change the server side code to use a new JSON encoder (perhaps one with different white space behaviour)
- Add an error message when status is not ok

When that happens, all those old versions of your app will prevent you from doing this.  Instead, do the parse correctly today to buy yourself peace in the future.  NSJSONSerialization is easy to use and will quickly parse the result handling each of the above cases.

Comment: @ChalamphongPandey Absolutely. Never assume some one else's code will give you exactly what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how to include double quotes in a string?

[How to escape double quotes in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352323/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-string)

The standard means of escaping characters in a C-like language is with a backslash, so you'd want to compare the result to the string `"{\"status\":\"ok\"}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to include a literal quotation mark in an Objective-C string?

```
if ([returnedText isEqualToString:@"{\"status\":\"ok\"}"]) {
    // success!
} else {
    // failure :-(
}
```

Of course, you should be *very* sure that you're only going to get this *exact* string back... in particular, can you ensure that your returned JSON won't contain any whitespace that you're not expecting?

Comment: yes, our server will send the exact same string back and i was told this is not going to change for a long time but now that i think about it, I should probably parse it. "Precaution is better than cure" Thanks for your answer though, has been bugging me for a while now that thing, could be helpful some other day

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @DrC in his/her [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391333/1071320), the right thing to do when comparing two JSON strings is to parse the JSON Strings to a Foundation object with the [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) class and then to compare the resulting Foundation objects. This approach takes care of the problem of the two JSON Strings having slightly different formatting or fields in a different order. So, for example, it's important that `"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"` and `"{\"b\":2,\"a\":1}"` are deemed to be equal because they are logically equal.

Here's a Swift function I put together which helps with this comparison:

```
class JSONAssert {

    class func assertEquals(expected: String, actual: String) {
    
        let expectedData = Data(expected.utf8)
        let actualData = Data(actual.utf8)
    
        let expectedObject: Any
        let actualObject: Any
    
        do {
            expectedObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: expectedData, options: [])
        } catch {
            XCTFail("Failed constructing a Foundation object from `expected` (i.e. \(expected)): \(error)")
            return
        }
    
        do {
            actualObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: actualData, options: [])
        } catch {
            XCTFail("Failed constructing a Foundation object from `actual` (i.e. \(actual)): \(error)")
            return
        }
    
        guard let expectedDictionary = expectedObject as? NSDictionary else {
            XCTFail("Failed casting expected object (i.e. \(expectedObject)) to an NSDictionary")
            return
        }
    
        guard let actualDictionary = actualObject as? NSDictionary else {
            XCTFail("Failed casting actual object (i.e. \(actualObject)) to an NSDictionary")
            return
        }
    
        XCTAssertEqual(expectedDictionary, actualDictionary)
    }
}
```